# Calculate the flux of the field $\mathbf{F} = k\left(\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}\right)$ out of an arbitrary closed surface not intersecting $(0,0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

> Calculate the flux of the field $$\mathbf{F} = k\left(\frac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|^3}\right)$$ where $\mathbf{r}=\langle x,y,z\rangle$ out of an arbitrary closed surface not intersecting $(0,0,0)$.

**My attempt**

I get 
$$\operatorname{div} \mathbf{F} = 0$$
Using Gauss’s theorem I get that the flux crossing an arbitrary surface must be $0$ since no flux is produced.

The **answer** is however $4k\pi$ if the surface envelopes $(0,0,0)$ and otherwise it is $0$. How can this be true? How can any flux pass any surface if no flux is created anywhere? My understanding is obviously flawed, but I can’t pinpoint where.

Comment: If the surface encloses the origin, then you get a problem that your divergence calculation is *not* correct at the origin. In fact in the sense of distribution theory there is a delta function divergence at zero, which gives this kind of behavior. This is really not that unusual in physics: a point charge at the origin creates a very similar effect.

Comment: You also can see by symmetry considerations that there must be a flux: if your surface is a sphere centered at the origin, note that your field points outward (or inward if $k<0$) at every point, so there must be net flux.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, that explains some of it. But how would I arrive at $4k\pi?$ What's the method I would use?

Comment: Try it for a sphere centered at the origin; in that case you can do a direct calculation. For a more general surface, artificially add another boundary term corresponding to a sphere centered at the origin, then note that the flux outside this sphere vanishes. (The other way to do it is to use distribution theory to identify the divergence of that field as a certain multiple of the Dirac delta function, but that requires some more setup.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \vec{F} = \left( \frac{kx}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^{3}},\frac{ky}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^{3}}, \frac{kz}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^{3}}\right),$
$ (x,y,z)\in R^3\setminus\{0\}.$

We'll use spherical of coordinates:

$ x = r\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta),\ \  y = r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta), \ \ z = r\sin(\theta).$

$ 0< \phi< 2\pi, \ \  -\frac{1}{2}< \theta < \frac{1}{2}\pi.$

Let

$ I =\left\{(\phi, \theta): 0<\phi< 2\pi, -\frac{1}{2}<\theta<\frac{1}{2}\pi \right\}$

and

$\Phi: I \rightarrow S. $

Differential form of flux

$\omega^2_{F} = \frac{k}{|r|^3} (xdy\wedge dz + ydz\wedge dx + zdx \wedge dy).$

Therefore

$ \Phi^{*}\omega_{F}(\phi,\theta) = \frac{k}{|r|^3} \left|\begin{matrix}x&y&z\\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi} \\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} \end{matrix}\right|=\frac{k}{|r|^3}\left|\begin{matrix}r\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)& r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)& r\sin(\theta) \\ -r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)& r\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)& 0 \\ -rcos(\phi)\sin(\theta)& -r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)& r\cos(\theta) \end{matrix}\right|d\phi \wedge d\theta = k\cos(\phi)d\phi \wedge d\theta.$

$\Phi = \int\int_{(S)}\omega^2_{F}= +\int\int_{I}\Phi^{*}\omega_{F}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}k \cos(\theta)d\theta = 4\pi k. $

Answer (score 1):

If a surface $S$ encloses the origin then the flux isn't defined on each point in the enclosed space, so you can't use the Divergence Theorem. To solve for that case draw a sphere $S_1$ around the origin s.t. $S_1$ is inside of $S$ (Since $S$ doesn't pass through the origin this is always possible). Now you can see that in $S-S_1$ the flux is $0$, as it's a closed surface which doesn't enclose the origin. Hence the flux in $S$ and $S_1$ is the same. Now it's fairly easy to calculate the flux in the sphere using the spherical coordinates

Comment: No, you're wrong. If $S$ *encloses* the origin (but the origin does not lie on the surface), then certainly the flux is defined. But the hypotheses of the Divergence Theorem do not hold.

Comment: @TedShifrin The flux function isn't defined at the origin, so you can't calculate the divergence of $F$ at the origin. If you try to exclude the origin for this cause the enclosed space isn't compact, which violates the conditions of the Divergence Theorem. Anyway I was trying to say that one can't use the Divergence Theorem when $S$ encloses the origin. Of course the flux is defined at $S$, which is why this problem is well-defined.

Comment: @TedShifrin We require $F$ to be continuously differentiable at $V$, but it's not even defined at the origin. As I said I was trying to point out why we can't use the Divergence Theorem.

Comment: I'm saying your first sentence is wrong. Read it carefully and read what I wrote carefully. There's no such thing as a "flux function." The *flux across the surface $S$* is a numerical quantity, and it makes perfectly fine sense.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add on inside the surface S. So thanks for pointing it out. When it comes to terminology since English isn't my first language it might be tricky, but I guess it's clear enough so you can see to what I'm refering to.

Comment: You're still misusing the word flux. You mean the *divergence* is not defined at every point inside $S$. I'm insisting on careful use of language so that your remarks will not confuse other readers. (I've taught multivariable calculus for approximately 45 years. It's confusing enough without errors in language.)